# How to allow incoming connection on a particular port from specific IP

Tags: mongodb, docker, port, iptables, centos6

I am running mongodb in a docker container with 27017 port exposed with host to allow remote incoming connection. I want to block incoming connection on this port except a particular IP. I tried with iptables but it is not working. Maybe because of the docker service for which iptables commands need to be modified.

However I used the following commands:

```
myserver>iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s 10.10.4.232 --dport 27017 -j ACCEPT
myserver>iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s 0.0.0.0/0 --dport 27017 -j DROP
myserver>service iptables save
```

Then tried the following to check

```
mylocal>telnet myserver 27017
```

It is connected. So iptables is not working.

How do I do it?

I am using centos 6.8 and running mongodb 10 in docker container.

Comment: Check if this helps you : https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/mongodb-allow-remote-access/

Comment: It works if mongodb is running in the server itself not in a docker container.

Answer (score 1):

First, enable the source IP you wish to connect:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 27017 -s 10.10.4.232 -j ACCEPT
```

Then DROP all the rest:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 27017 -j DROP
```